# I2C lines coupled?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, i2c

I am using a 5k pullup resistor on my SDA and SCL lines. I am using a 62kHz clock signal on SCL. I have made two boards so far. For the first board I routed all the traces myself, but for the second I used the auto-router feature in Eagle. I routed the important traces myself, but for everything else, including SCL and SDA, I left things up to the auto-router.

For the first board, I get good performance on the I2C lines: 
[image: Clean]

However on the second board (auto-routed I2C lines), the traces show that the SDA and SCL lines are coupled:[image: Dirty]

From the logic capture, it appears that the communication still works on the second board. However the analog levels tell a different story.

Moreover, after running this test program on my microcontroller (PIC16LF), the program goes into a bad state. What I mean by this is that the I2C lines begin to float, and the clock signal becomes "stretched". I also have a debug LED that toggles with a certain event, and the pin the controls that LED seems to let go, as the LED flickers in a somewhat random way.

My questions are therefore:

**1) Is this in fact caused by the layout?**

**2) What would cause the program to go into a bad state?**

To give an idea of how bad the SDA trace looks, here is a screenshot of the the layout:

[image: Snake]

Comment: If the lines appear to be shorted then they very well may be shorted. Have you checked with an ohm meter? Many of I2C type chips have SCL and SDA on adjacent pins and you may very well have a solder short between those pins. If you etched your own board there may still be traces of copper between the pads causing the short.

Comment: By the "steps" that show up on your logic analyzer it seems the trace capacitance is too high for 5k, so rise time is too long. Try changing the resistors for 2k2 or even 1k. A proper scope would also help showing this.

Comment: BTW - With an experience like this - whatever the root cause of the I2C problem - you may come to side with those like me that find zero utility with auto-routing traces on a PC board.

Comment: Looking at your routing, the one thing I notice quite clearly is your pull-up resistors connect together than then to a very long thin trace off to wherever your power supply is. That long thin trace will mean your resistors are being pulled up to a weak voltage rail, meaning the SCL/SDA lines will float around together (your pull up resistors essentially connect them together).

Comment: It doesn't surprise me you are having issues in any case - the whole board looks a complete routing mess with components randomly strewn around everywhere. If you spend the time to making a PCB look clean and neatly laid out, it will always work better.

Comment: Match up the two blue traces, they sure look like the pull-up resistors are shorted or misrouted somehow. High and high give full voltage. Low and low give 0. High and low give a middle voltage.

Comment: Okay, thanks for all the comments. Lesson learned for auto-routing. FWIW the electrical connections are correct, even though it appears otherwise.

Comment: The lines are not shorted. What Tom says is correct. They are being pulled up by a long trace to the 3V3 rail.

Comment: With a 1k pullup it does work, but only for a short, random amount of time. I.e. the program will run on the PIC for anywhere from 13 seconds to a minute. But eventually it goes "weird" and my debug LED goes haywire. What causes this, and how to fix? Decoupling capacitors on PIC? Currently using 1 next to +3V3 and ground. 1uF.

Comment: A thing : Wrong power source or resistant to short circuits or signal load effect...

Comment: Your first board shows "SCL" as data, while its "SDA" sure looks like clock. Your second board makes more sense. Are you sure that your second board routing didn't swap "SCL" for "SDA" in error?

Comment: @glen_geek Good catch. But those are just labels on the logic analyzer program, meaning that I had switched the leads at one point.

Comment: Fixed the signal quality issue with board surgery. Cut lines and added direct wires... analog traces good. Now if anyone can give a hint as to why the PIC would go haywire under bad I2C communications, please comment, or answer question!

Comment: I'm thinking that SDA-SCL lines would charge capacitively over time, and eventually corrupt program memory?? Please comment!

Comment: I am going to go ahead and disagree with the commentors above.  The routing looks messy for sure, but overall the traces are still rather short, and I2C at 62 kHz is not that demanding.  Likewise, the long supply wire for the pullup will still have orders of magnitude less resistance than the pull up resistor itself. I think you have a partial short, bad contact, or miswired signal somewhere.  Also note that a problem with the power supply could cause problem both for I2C and cause other glitches on the MCU.  This is where the bad routing kills you, it becomes really hard to diagnose errors.

Comment: why PIC went haywire? These two lines rested near the half-way  between logic 1 and logic 0. That's no-man's land where shoot-thru current can skyrocket. It shouldn't happen on SDA or SCL drivers (because they're pull-down only), but perhaps can happen on SDA, SCL receivers. We're all guessing, because now you've cleared the fault without finding the cause.

Comment: @Evan Looks like the auto-router did place several vias way too close to other pins or pads. I did use a continuity test on all the traces before and after stuffing the board, and didn't find any shorts. But your comment on bad routing is well received. I'm going to punt on the cause and just to a better layout next time.